# How to use Mathematica's Moment Generating Function?

Tags: distributions

Given the following p.d.f., which is the p.d.f. of the ratio between a complex Gaussian and a Chi-squared RVs:

\begin{equation*}
 f_U(u)=\exp\Big\{{-\frac{1}{4 u^2}}\Big\} \,\frac{\left(8 n u^2-1\right) I_n\left(\frac{1}{4
   u^2}\right)+I_{n+1}\left(\frac{1}{4 u^2}\right)}{4 |u|^3},  
\end{equation*}
where $n$ is a constant integer and $I_n(z)$ is the modified Bessel function of the first kind.

I'd like to use Mathematica to find its Moment-generating function or at least its mean and variance.

I tried Mathematica's "MomentGeneratingFunction" and "Mean"/"Variance" functions but it was to no avail as the output is just the p.d.f. again as shown below.

[image]

I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong or if that is not possible with those Mathematica's functions. Follows below the code I'm using.

```
f[n_, u_] = Exp[(-1/(4*(u^2)))]*((8*n*(u^2) - 1)*BesselI[n, 1/(4*(u^2))] + BesselI[n + 1, 1/(4*(u^2))]) / (4*(Abs[u]^3));

dist = ProbabilityDistribution[f[10, u], {u, -Infinity, Infinity}]

MomentGeneratingFunction[dist, t]
```

Comment: You would first need to set-up a black box for your distribution, say `dist = ProbabilityDistribution[pdf, {u, -Infinity, Infinity}]` ... Then you can try the Wolfram functions like `MomentGeneratingFunction[dist, t]`. I haven't tried it for your example, but since your pdf is quite complicated, I doubt anything useful will come of the exercise, but happy to be surprised!

Comment: @wolfies, thanks! I've just tried and as you said nothing useful came through... I've got the same as before, i.e., the p.d.f. as in the picture above.

Comment: Suggest you enter the code you are using (not as a picture), but as part of your question, so that others can copy and paste what you are doing.

Comment: @wolfies, OK, I've just updated to post to include the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "11.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

f[n_, u_] = 
  Exp[-1/(4*u^2)] ((8*n*u^2 - 1)*BesselI[n, 1/(4*u^2)] + 
      BesselI[n + 1, 1/(4*u^2)])/(4*Abs[u]^3);
```

`f` is only defined in the limit for `u == 0`

```
f[n_, 0] = Limit[f[n, u], u -> 0]

(* (-1 + 2 n)/Sqrt[2 π] *)
```

The built-in functions such as [`Mean`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mean.html) require a distribution as an input rather than a pdf. As pointed out in the comments by @wolfies, use your pdf as an input to [`ProbabilityDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ProbabilityDistribution.html). You should also include any assumptions.

```
dist[n_] = 
  ProbabilityDistribution[f[n, u], {u, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
   Assumptions -> {Element[n, Integers], n > 0}];
```

The assumptions are used by built-in functions using [`DistributionParameterAssumptions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DistributionParameterAssumptions.html)

```
DistributionParameterAssumptions[dist[n]]

(* {n ∈ Integers, n > 0} *)
```

The [`PDF`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PDF.html) has even symmetry about `u == 0`

```
PDF[dist[n], u] == PDF[dist[n], -u]

(* True *)
```

Plots of the `PDF` show this symmetry.

```
plt = Plot[Evaluate@Table[PDF[dist[n], u], {n, 5, 1, -1}], {u, -2, 2},
  PlotRange -> {0, 3.75},
  WorkingPrecision -> 20,
  AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 12, Bold] & /@ {"u", "PDF"}),
  PlotLegends ->
   Placed[
    (StringForm["n = ``", #] & /@ Range[5, 1, -1]),
    {0.7, 0.5}],
  ImageSize -> 432]
```

[image]

As expected from the even symmetry of the `PDF`, the means (and all other odd moments) are zero

```
Mean[dist[n]]

(* 0 *)
```

The variance is only defined for `n > 1` (the following calculation is quite slow)

```
(seq = {#, Variance[dist[#]]} & /@ Range[1, 6]) // Column
```

[image]

Then,

```
variance[n_] = FindSequenceFunction[seq[[2 ;;]], n]

(* 1/(4 (-1 + n) n) *)
```

Alternatively,

```
Assuming[n > 1, Variance[dist[n]] // Simplify]

(* 1/(4 (-1 + n) n) *)
```

The even moments of `dist[n]` are only defined for orders less than `2n`. For example, for `dist[10]`

```
(moments = {2 #, Moment[dist[10], 2 #]} & /@ Range[10]) // Column
```

[image]

Comment: Dear, I've just simulated with Matlab, n = 10 and 1e6 iterations and the variance I've found is 0.2783, which is different from 1/(4*(-1 + n)*n) = 0.0028. Do you know what could be wrong?

Comment: This is the link to the matlab script I used to check the value: https://pastebin.com/WDsA91eQ

Comment: It seems the variance is given by n/4*(n-1). I've reached at this by multiplying  1/(4*(-1 + n)*n)  by n^2.

Comment: @FelipeAugustodeFigueiredo - Please write your Matlab script in the Wolfram language. I do not have access to Matlab and do not know its syntax. This is a site for Mathematica.

Comment: Sorry, I'm almost illiterate on Mathematica, this is my first real attempt on this. I will try to translate into Mathematica's syntax.